# Digital stereo (IEC958) only , ALC1150,Ubuntu 16.04 AMD64

Tags: 16.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome remix with ALC1150 onboard sound which is a 7.1 surround chip,and can only use stereo digital output thru the onboard optical output.

MB:Asrock F2A88X Extreme 6+

How to enable Dolby Digital 5.1?

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here.. I used to have this working on 14.04 following the relatively complex module building processes referenced [here ](http://askubuntu.com/questions/483555/problem-with-5-1-ac-3-through-alsa-pulseaudio-on-spdif-ubuntu-14-04) - but after upgrading to 16.04 this is no longer working and I'm back to stereo only.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually so simple that it's silly that it's not included in the default gnome audio control panel.

Step 1:

```
sudo apt install libavresample-dev pavucontrol libasound2-plugins-extra
```

Step 2:

```
pavucontrol
```

Step 3:

Tick all the boxes for the advanced audio codecs

Step 4:

Enjoy amazing sound over S/PDIF out (optical or coax) to a speaker set that supports it.
[image]