# PulseAudio not passing AC3/DTS, downmixing to stero

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa, spdif, ac3

Running Kubuntu (KDE) 20.04

**TLDR**: Pusleaudio won't pass AC3/DTS to my external DAC via coaxial S/PDIF, but ALSA will if an application has a setting to direct output to ALSA.

I'm using my motherboard's coaxial SPDIF connection to connect to my 5.1 speaker system that has it's own DAC ([Logitech Z906](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/speakers/z906-surround-sound-system.980-000467.html)).  The only way I've been able to get 5.1 surround to work is with VLC audio set to ALSA audio output > S/PDIF when available, 5.1 Surround Output.  So I know the hardware works if I can go directly to ALSA taking Pulseaudio out of the picture.  Unfortunately, very few applications, and no web browsers offer a setting (that I can find) to force output directly to ALSA.  I've been researching how to get Pulseaudio to pass AC3/DTS directly to my sound system but just can't seem to make it work.  So watching movies with AC3 5.1 in a web browser (Plex, Netflix, etc), all get down mixed by Pulseaudio to two channel PCM.

I've tried the steps posted on the [Help Ubuntu: DigitalAC-3Pulseaudio](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DigitalAC-3Pulseaudio) and that didn't help.  I've also seen several references to change the default speaker channels in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf/` to `default-sample-channels=6`, didn't work either.

Additionally, I tried to set the card profile per [Problem with 5.1 AC-3 through Alsa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483555/problem-with-5-1-ac-3-through-alsa-pulseaudio-on-spdif-ubuntu-14-04) to `pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:iec958-ac3-surround-51` and I get the error "No such profile: output:iec958-ac3-surround-51".  (Probably not surprising since this answer was for Ubuntu 14.04)

**pavucontrol:** (same settings show up in Pulseaudio Volume Control GUI)

***Configuration tab***: the only options for digital output are "*Digtial Stereo (IEC958) Output*" and "*Digtial Stereo (IEC958) Output+Analog Stereo Input*".  Several websites said this is correct as Pusleaudio "should" pass AC3/DTS directly to the external DAC via S/PDIF.  I have selected "*Digtial Stereo (IEC958) Output*".

***Output Devices tab***: I've selected Port "*Digital Output (S/PDIF)*" and under "Advanced" I have *DTS*, *AC3*, *MPEG*, and *AAC* selected.

**AlsaMixer**:
By default after boot it always comes up with *PCM* on, and *Front* Speakers On.  Every other channel is muted.  I unmute *Surround*, and *LFE* and make the volume sliders full.  This doesn't seem to help either.  AlsaMixer appears to be set to the correct sound device Card: *HDA ATI SB*, Chip *Realteck ALC892*.  If I select F6 to "select sound card" 3 items are listed, HDA ATI SB (the one I'm using), my webcam, and my NVDIA graphics hard (HDMI).  So it appears the correct sound card is selected.

I looked into getting rid of Pulseaudio all together and just use ALSA... but it seems like Pulseaudio is heavily integrated and would cause a lot of issues if removed (the dependency list is huge, including KDE, try to remove it (sudo apt remove) and it will take down KDE all together leaving me with a command line only system.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!