# No Audio From Digital Output (S/PDIF) On Fresh Install 21.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 21.10, spdif

Title pretty much says it all. Before installing 21.10, I tried a bunch of solutions on darn near every thread here on askubuntu but to no avail.

Mobo is a Asus Z170.

If I output audio to my HDMI it works, no problem.

When I try to output via my digital output (S/PDIF) nothing is coming through. Sometimes I can use 'Test' and hear "left input" and "right input" but if I try to play any sounds or videos or youtube - it essentially 'kills it', and no more audio is heard.

For example - if I select HDMI and run the audio test, I can hear 'front right' and 'front left', then if I select Digital Output and run the tests, I hear 'front right' and 'front left' - so it would appear to be working.

If I play *any audio at all* I no longer hear anything when using Digital Output. Once I stop any currently playing audio, select HDMI (and run the tests), then select Digital Output again, the test audio will work again. But once any audio is played again (including system alert sounds) the Digital Output stops working again (however, oddly, the 'Bark' alert sound seems to work while none others do)

I had this issue on 20.04 and after hours of frustration decided to do a fresh install to 21.10 to see if it resolved the issue (which it did not).

[image]

I can see the volume going up and down in the 'Output' section of the Sound settings - as if it's recognizing that audio is playing. It's just not actually outputting that audio.

I also installed pavucontrol and it additionally sees the audio (volume going up and down):

[image]

Additionally - in Alsamixer I have everything turned up and you can see the S/PDIF enabled with the 00 (as per the sound troubleshooting instructions):

[image]

Do I have to install the realtek audio drivers for my motherboard on Linux? I'm a bit clueless at this point as to how to make this work.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - I continued digging through post after post and trying fix after fix.

I eventually stumbled across [this answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1290441/674328).

In summary:

Configure `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`

replace: `; default-sample-rate = 44100`

with: `default-sample-rate = 48000`

Apparently it's a mismatch with the sampling rate - which is why I could see the audio as if it were playing - but couldn't hear it.